# Why won't the text within the quotes section move down

Tags: html, css, margin

I have added a margin to the .quotes-text selector however it moves the whole quotes section down not just the text within the quotes section. Any idea what might be causing this? Code below.

```css
.quotes {
  height: 344px;
  background: #bf4b54;
}

.quote-text {
  font-size: 2rem;
  max-width: 860px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes">
  <div class="quote-text">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque soluta necessitatibus a autem obcaecati officiis reiciendis. - Head Chef</span>
  </div>
  <img src="" alt="" class="chef">
</div>
```

Comment: your piece of code is missing the margin part. You may read this to understand what happens with vertical margins https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing ;) look at the section : **No content separating parent and descendants**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text to move down (but not the section) use `padding` instead of `margin`.